# How to deal with Azure Subscriptions for clients?

Tags: azure, subscription, billing

I'm fairly new to Azure. I have a personal website in the cloud and played around with some stuff, but that's it. Since I have my first client project coming up in which I will use certain Azure functionality, I was wondering on how to deal with billing.

I will of course put all the resources needed for the client under a new resource group, but the thing I'm wondering about is which subscription to link that resource group to.

Option 1 :
I link it to my own subscription. Least interesting as I would have to send the client an invoice every month charging him the costs that I made through my subscription for his project.

Option 2 :
I add a new subscription under my Azure account, using the client's credit card. This is the most interesting for me as I can see all resources under my Azure account and the client gets billed automatically. But you have to convince the client to give you their credit card information so you can create the subscription.

Option 3 :
The client makes his own Azure account, with a subscription under that account using his credit card. This is less interesting for me as I have to manage 2 Azure accounts. But it's more interesting for the client as they can create their own account and don't have to give me their credit card details.

What's the typical way to go about this? Are there other options that I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this is off-topic for Stack Overflow, as it's really up to you (and you'll only get opinions). And there is not necessarily a "typical" way to approach this. That said: option 3 also affords you the ability to be added to the resource group(s) needed for you to manage your customer's app. It might be worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor question over all (for Stack Overflow at least). But common sense says:

1. they give you access to their subscription(s)
2. you create resources in your subscriptions, bill them.

Comment: 2 is my option 1, which is not practical. If you have several clients and you have to figure out every month how much to bill each of them, that's just not practical.